# Partitioning a list in n sublists with constrains in their sums

Tags: version-10, cluster-analysis

Is there a way to put cluster level limits on clusters? For example, if I run:

```
FindClusters[{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 10}]
```

I get back two lists, `{{1, 2, 3, 4, 4}, {6, 7, 10}}`. But lets say I only want each cluster to have a sum of 15 or fewer and potentially get `{{2, 3, 10}, {6, 3, 1}, {7, 4, 4}}`

As far as I can tell, this is not possible to express with a distance function, so maybe clustering is the wrong tool for the job?

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: _"I only want each cluster to have a sum of 15 or fewer"_ is very lax. You still have way too many possible combinations

Comment: @belisarius, That is by design. If possible, I would like to randomly get `n` solutions to this problem.

Comment: But ...how many clusters? How many elements per cluster?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to be able to just give a number of clusters (in the case, 3). Max elements per cluster should not matter unless they meet that limiting condition (also, the inversion of the limiting condition could exist, so that would mean 3 clusters of fewer)

Comment: Clustering is based on similarity of elements, but your condition is not explicitly based on similarity.  For you, the clusters {4, 5, 6} and {1, 14} each sum to 15, but differ drastically as far as clustering algorithms.  It seems you want to use Tuples with constraints, not FindClusters.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, any examples on how to do that (can't seem to find anything explicitly designed for solving constraints on sets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Quiet[<< Combinatorica`;]
l = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 10};
f[l_, n_, min_, max_] := Module[{part, s},
                         While[(s = (Tr /@ (part = RandomKSetPartition[l, n])); 
                              Not[And @@ Thread[min < s < max]])];
                         part]
f[l, 3, 5, 15]
(* {{1, 10}, {2, 4, 7}, {3, 4, 6}} *)
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without holding all sets to be the same size?

Comment: They aren't the same size ...

Comment: Oh, my bad. Looks good then, I'll try on larger data sets and see how performance is. Thank you.

Comment: This is silly, but I can't seem to bound it both ways (between min and max). Replacing the inside with `Module[{part, s}, 
 While[Or @@ 
   Thread[s = (Tr /@ (part = RandomKSetPartition[l, n])) < max  && 
      s > min]` gives nonsensical answers.

Comment: @soandos `Thread[]` doesn't work that way ...

Comment: So I can only bound it on one side (the change I made was inside thread, still returning a boolean)?

Comment: @soandos Let me see if I can quick-fix the code for that. Not much time right now

Comment: @soandos:  I think you still haven't specified your question properly, i.e., in a way that will lead to an answer.  Is this what you seek?  "Given a list myList containing n integers (possibly non-distinct), with target subset size range [minsize, maxsize], find a partition (all partitions?) of myList such that each subset's elements sum to a value in the specified range [minsum, maxsum], or return a flag stating no such partition of myList exists."?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork. Would like some way to get some amount of partitions, but will have have a need to prove "ALL" if that matters. Otherwise, spot on

Comment: @soandos There you go

Comment: @belisarius, thank you, testing now

Comment: @belisarius pretty sure there is something wrong with the condition (maybe something should be an And? can't seem to be able to fix it), but it doesn't work. `f[l, 3, 10, 15]` gives `{{1, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 10}, {6, 7}}` as an answer

Comment: @soandos I think I fixed it now